# How do I figure out the nameservers Avahi is using?

Tags: ubuntu, avahi, mdns

Avahi now runs in Ubuntu to serve as a nameserver on 127.0.1.1.  How do I figure out which nameserver(s) Avahi auto-discovered to use?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is ultimately still coming from Network Manager.

I was able to find my eth0 device with:

```
# nmcli con show
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE            DEVICE
Wired connection 1  eaa034b4-c9a6-3469-9c20-d0922e777d6b  802-3-ethernet  eth0
cni0                6f4e3d15-6ba1-43a2-8c29-609676e5b7fc  bridge          cni0
docker0             5112d4fe-6490-4f9a-bce2-02651b2bd4a7  bridge          docker0
```

and then find the nameservers that avahi ulimately uses with:

```
# nmcli con show "Wired connection 1" | grep domain_name_servers
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 172.20.43.4 172.20.38.12 10.100.2.155
```